# Applying counter on pandas on unique columns values

Tags: python, pandas, counter

My data looks like this

[image]

Same user can have multiple shift IDs. So in nurse_id column I have repeating IDs.

I want to create counter on new_state for unique nurse.

Currently when I do

```
Counter(df["new_stat"])
```

It gives

```
Counter({'D': 15123, 'R': 29300, 'not_active': 2581, 'N': 21455})
```

But it counts duplicate values of IDs as well.

How can I create counter on `new_stat` for unique `nurse_id`?

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe... maybe you can use `df.groupby(['nurse_id,'last_login'])['new_stat'].count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas solution is [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df.groupby('nurse_id')['new_stat'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
```

Or [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
df.groupby(['nurse_id','new_stat']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

If need Counters objects per groups is possible use dictionary comprehension with `Series` constructor:

```
pd.Series({k: Counter(v['new_stat']) for k, v in df.groupby('nurse_id')})
```